# JSON encode PHP AJAX jQuery response error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am having a problem with getting back the response from my PHP code. The JavaScript file says the JSON object is of length 0.

Here is my returned JSON from my **getalbums.php** script:

```
[
  {
    "album_id": "50ab2c3db9396",
    "username": "tusik",
    "title": "testalbum",
    "cover_photo_url": "http:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/Looking_Glass_Images\/tusik_testalbum_testpic.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "album_id": "50ab3b75a46fe",
    "username": "tusik",
    "title": "test",
    "cover_photo_url": "http:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/Looking_Glass_Images\/tusik_test_test.png"
  }
]
```

---

**getalbums.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
include("db.php");

$albumsArray = array();

$username = $_GET['uid'];
//Preventing MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$sql = "SELECT album_id,username,title,cover_photo_url FROM albums WHERE   albums.username='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo $count;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    $albumsArray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $albumsArray );
?>
```

If I type `/getalbums.php?uid=tusik` I get the JSON from above so I know that page works.

---

**albums.js**

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
return results[1] || 0;
}

var username = $.urlParam('uid');

var data = "uid=" + username;    
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getalbums.php",
  data: data,
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false
}).done(function(data) {
    //Do work

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

The code gives me this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'album_id' of undefined
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** 
Fixed my problem jeroen's suggestion was partially right. `{'uid':username}` should of read `{"uid":username}`.

Comment: Why don't you first check what `data` contains? Perhaps php echoed out a warning or error.

Comment: When I print data to the screen it says []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send both the key and the value to the server in you ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getalbums.php",
  data: {'uid': username},    // here
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false
}).done(function(data) {
```

You were just sending the data without a key, so that is why `$_GET['uid']` was empty / unset and your query returned 0 rows.

**Edit:** You are also invalidating your json with this line:

```
echo $count;
```

You need to make sure that only the `json_encode` line gets echoed / returned to the jQuery callback function so just remove it or comment it out.

Comment: Ok well If I had 15 rep I would up vote this. Thank you so much for the help but I still have a problem. The returned data is of length 0 still. Any solutions?

Comment: Ok that was from my debuging but it didn't effect anything since it was null in the first place. How do I get this line to work?`console.log(data[0].album_id);` The data is still coming back with length 0.

Comment: @Preston Tighe Does the php script work for a normal request?

Comment: Yes I tried it with `$albumsArray = array( "album" => "");` then I set album to something then echoed it. I could pull the album key from the albums.js file. And like I said `/getalbums.php?uid=tusik` works too.

Comment: Well figured out the problem. `{'uid': username}` should read `{"uid": username}` but I just did `var data = "uid=" + username;` and it worked.

Comment: That's because `processData` is set to `false`. In this case, you have to provide a query string. If you set it to `true`, `data` can be an object, and jQuery will process it into a query string.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Wow, good catch, I hadn't even noticed that option. Single or double quotes should not make a difference though, should it?

Comment: @jeroen In Javascript they are the same.

Comment: @bažmegakapa That's what I thought so the comment of the OP did not make a lot of sense to me...

Answer (score 4):

If you set `dataType: 'json'`, `data` should already contain the parsed data, not the JSON string. So calling `parseJSON()` is an unnecessary step - it will try to parse your (already parsed) Javascript array, which is of course not a string containing JSON, so it fails and returns `null`.

You can also check this on [the manual page for `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (emphasis mine):

> #### dataType
>
> **"json"**: Evaluates the response as JSON and ***returns a JavaScript
>   object***. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any
>   malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org
>   for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

This means you should be able to simply write:

```
...
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0].album_id);
})
...
```

Comment: So what is the proper way to return the album_id in the json object? Sorry I am very new to javascript.

Comment: @PrestonTighe Updated my answer. If you try to write `data` itself on the console, you will see that it is already parsed.

Comment: I have tried something of this nature and it gives me an error. The error is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'album_id' of undefined.` When I try to print with `console.log(data);` it gives me an object where the album property is of length 0.

Comment: @PrestonTighe Use the Network tab of your inspector (I use the built-in Chrome Inspector) to analyze what data is coming back from the server. The response must be valid JSON.

Comment: When I do this and look at the response tab. The response is blank.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try simple eval() function. [Click here](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/p/json.html) if you want more details about JSON and eval().

```
var test = eval("(" + data + ")"); OR var test = eval(data);
```

I have already tried this in my lots of application and this is working fine for me.